# Inner div overflowing container

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s inside a `div`. I want the second `div` to fill up to the bottom of the container. I tried various `height: 100%;`, `height: inherit;`, `height: auto;`, etc. and different values for `display` css property, but didn't succeed. Please help.
**Html:**

```html
<div style='height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;'>
  <div style='background-color: red;'>
    <label>Test</label>
  </div>
  <div style='height: inherit; background-color: green;'>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RvD6/)
**Note:** The second div has some rows and then a footer. I want the rows to be hidden as per the height. But the footer of the second div should be visible.
**Another note:**
The container is re-sizable (using JQuery Re-size). Hence I do not want to set the height of the second `div`. That will make it static. I want the second div to have dynamic height. i.e. Expanding yo the bottom of the container, always.

Comment: Have you tried with `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Yes. See Anand's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

### HTML:

```
<div id="con">
    <div id="top">
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">sdsdfsdfsdfs sdfs dfsdf sdf sd ff</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#con {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: relative;

}
#top {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#bottom {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Take a look and see what you think. (you will have to push down inside to put text etc using `padding-top: 20px;`

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/QS3Vp/2)

Comment: Yes, i think this does it. I'll check soon

Comment: Thanks. The `position` property did it.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
**overflow:hidden;**

<div style='height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;overflow:hidden;'>
    <div style='background-color: red;'>
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div style='height: inherit; background-color: green;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or Else you have to master div height **auto** and inner keep **100%** some content inside.

```
<div style='height: auto; width: 100px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;'>
    <div style='background-color: red;'>
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div style='height: 100%; background-color: green;'>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that would hide the lower part of the second div. I don't want that.

Comment: try Bottom Sample its is better.

Answer (score 2):

when you do `height: inherit;`, the target container acquires the height of parent, that's why, your inner green div is taking `height:100px` and hence it is overshooting.

You should **NOT DO overflow:hidden**, as it will eat up your lower content.

What you should do is to either give percentage height to both your containers like

```
<div id="parentDiv" style='height: 100px; width: 100px; 
                             background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;'>
    <div id="topDiv" style='background-color: red;height:30%'>
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div id="lowerDiv" style='height: 70%; background-color: green;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

or use javascript to set height of your containers, something like

```
$(window).resize(function(){
      var _heightT= $('#parentDiv').height();
      $('#topDiv').height(_height*0.3);
      $('#lowerDiv').height(_height*0.7);

 })
```

I would suggest to give your Parent container a fixed height(deduced according to the window size, through javascript/jQuery), so that it is consistent across all browsers, and your inner containers, a percentage height, or atleast your top container a fixed height, and lower container a `min-height` and `overflow-y:auto`

Comment: Yes, javascript is the last solution. But I thought there might be some css instead of making it complicated using javascript. +1 for that.

Comment: see, you cannot assign 100% height, because that would mean, height of parent, and again it will overshoot, you cannot assign `height:auto`, cause, that would mean, flexible height(might or might not stretch to the end), your only option is to give height to both your containers, either through css or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;'>
    <div style='background-color: red;'>
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div style='height: inherit; background-color: green;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

According that we don't want to use `overflow:hidden`

Updated  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9RvD6/23/)

```
<div style='height: auto; width: 100px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;'>
    <div style='background-color: red;'>
        <label>Header</label>
    </div>
    <div style='height: 100%; background-color: green;'>
        <label>Body</label>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you read the other comments? The OP already said `overflow:hidden` doesn't do what they want.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't see when I post my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a percentage based height like you suggested, but the thing is when you set the bottom div to `height:100%;` that means 100% of the parent div's height which is 100px and it'll go outside the box, instead you could give the top div a 25% height and the bottom div 75% height, like this:

```
<div style='height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid black;'>
    <div style='height:25%; background-color: red;'>
    <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div style='height: 75%; background-color: green;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abmenzel/9RvD6/20/)

Comment: You could assign the top div with a static height in pixels `width:25px` and then create a function that assigns the bottom div with a height of 100% -25px

Answer (score 0):

When you do `height:inherit`, it takes the height value from the parent `div`, which is the same as saying `height:100%`. But this causes the div to overflow because there is another inner-div child inside the main container `div`, which is taking a height equal to the default `line-height` of the `label` tag. You can try giving the inner div tags separate heights:

**HTML**:(same as your markup, just adding classes so you don't have to give inline styling)

```
<div class="p">
    <div class="c1">
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.p {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
.c1 {
    height:20%;
    background-color: red;
}
.c2 {
    height: 80%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/9RvD6/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `display:table` property in CSS. [See more](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display)

Add `display:table` to the wrap div and `display:table-row` for the children.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/9RvD6/21/)**

Comment: I have tried this. But instead of adjusting second div's height, it expands the container to accommodate the second div.